# Can you explain this recursive solution from Chap 3 Eloquent js?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am going through chapter 3 in eloquent javascript and recursion was just introduced and I am trying wrap my mind around this concept.

Also can someone explain the second parameter history in the function find ?

Has history already been defined ?

Consider this puzzle: by starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite amount of new numbers can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of such additions and multiplications that produce that number? For example, the number 13 could be reached by first multiplying by 3 and then adding 5 twice, whereas the number 15 cannot be reached at all.

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Comment: Keep in mind, `history` is just a string, nothing more.

Comment: in these cases, i find a console.log() or two can really clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

console.log will print the value returned by findSolution(24) where 24 is the target.

now, when the function findSolution() is executed, it invokes (calls) the function "find" with 2 parameters : start = 1, history = "1" then returns something to be printed.

"return"  sends back to the place the call was set. meaning find() is called within findSolution(), hence return will send back a value where it was called within findSolution.

in our case :

if start === target

```
return history //(to findSolution. let's call it "H")
return H to console.log() // prints 1
```

else if start > target

```
return null //(to findSolution, let's call it N)
return N to console.log() // prints null
```

otherwise if start is lesser than target, 
    return A || B

```
A = find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)")
B = find (start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")
```

meaning return A if A is truthy otherwise return B;
A or B are evaluated before the function returns.

let's go through it step by step :

find will be invoked again and again with start parameter incremented by 5
ie :

```
return find(1, "1")    //  start = 1,   history = "(1 + 5)"    
return find(6, history)   //   start = 6,   history = "(1 + 5 ) + 5"   
return find(11, history)    //  start = 11,   history = "(1 + 5) + 5 ) + 5"   
return find(16, history)    //  start = 16,   history = "(1 + 5) + 5 ) + 5 ) + 5"   
return find(21, history) start = 21,   history = "(1 + 5) + 5 ) + 5 ) + 5 ) + 5"
```

now the next value will be 26. since 26 > 22, "find" will return B instead

```
return find(63, history) start = 21 * 3 =  63,      
//since 63 > 24,  "null" is returned where start = 16,
```

start is 16 and not 63 because it is a parameter. It is not changed and knows nothing about the incrementation by 5 that occurred during the invocation.

find(21*3, history) , 48 > 24 so return null where start = 11
find(11 *3, history) , 33 > 24 so return null where start = 6
find(6*3, history) , start = 18 and 18 < 24 so A will be truthy start will be incremented by 5
return find( 18 + 5, history)
return find (23 + 5, history) 28 > 24, A is null, B is evaluated

... and so on and so on until start is equal 24

Answer (score 0):

History is specified when the function `find` is called. You cannot call the function `find` without also providing a value for history. Remember that the function won't run until it's called, so history doesn't get a value until it's told its value is `"1"` on the line `return find(1, "1");` The variable history is defined by being the thing after the comma whenever `find` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I remember banging my head against this one for a long time...

The author is defining the function `find` inside the function `findSolution`, which is pretty confusing

If I rewrite it this way, you will get it:

```
function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
}

function findSolution(target) {
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```